# eclipse plugin fails to load org.eclipse.pde.ui:Disabled

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

My plugin fails to be loaded in eclipse in ubuntu environment with following message

```
The following problems were found:
  The bundle is disabled: "org.eclipse.pde.ui:Disabled via PDE"
  Missing host JavaSE_0.0.0
```

The available JREs on the system are 1.7, 1.6 .

Can anyboday give a hint why this happens ? And how this can be solved ?

On Windows machine everything works well.

---

**UPDATE** : PDE Error log shows following

eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=1.6.0_24 java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86  Error Tue Jun 04 10:33:19 CEST 2013 FrameworkEvent ERROR  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "com.example.Enum2String_1.0.1 [303]" could not be resolved. Reason: The bundle is disabled: "org.eclipse.pde.ui:Disabled via PDE"     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Answer (score 1):

Bundles can be disabled by PDE in a number of ways, but the most likely cause is through the UI.  They can also be enabled through the UI.  To do so,  open up the Plugin registry view and find the disabled bundle.

1. Right click -> Show advanced operations
2. Right click again -> enable

Comment: I tried enabling this way, but I got no any response, the logger didn't show any information. How can I see the log of enabling the plugin ?

Comment: Also can you please let me know any possible reason when the bundle is disabled by PDE ?

Comment: I don't know any other reasons.  Perhaps you have a plugin that is doing this.  Another way to get rid of this is to start Eclipse with the -clean option.